# what is the meaning of the "diag" flag reported by gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm using gparted on a dual-boot system, and a partition that I think is used by Windows shows up with the "diag" flag, in spite of it being listed as an ext4 format.  Not readable, however, so the partition signature may be corrupt.  So I'm just confused.

I'd like to know what the flag means to gparted, and where it is in the MBR or perhaps the partition signature, and how I could see that same flag in the output of lsblk or some other command-line utility (I want to recognize it in a bash script).  Right now it's just an enigma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PonJar.  I'm collecting our conversation into another answer.

"diag" is reported by gparted.  The same flag is reported as "msftres" by parted, and the partitions are reported as "Microsoft Recovery Partition" in Windows 10's Disk Management.  It may be that the flag has other uses, but for my purposes, this means that the partition is for the benefit of Windows.  It appears that Microsoft does not bother with a filesystem signature for these partitions, so I can't make any inferences about the presence of data or its format.

For scripting, I've decided to use "parted /dev/<drive name> print" and filter the line(s) of interest.  For example, for partition 3, I might use

```
if parted /dev/sda print | \
    sed -e "1,/Number/"d" | \
    grep -e "^ *3 " | \
    fgrep msftres >/dev/null
then
    DIAG=1
else
    DIAG=0
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The parted manual is helpful for this question. It says;

```
‘DIAG’

(MS-DOS) - Enable this to indicate that a partition can be used as a diagnostics / recovery partition.
```

The full document is here https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/set.html

You should be able to output flags with

```
lsblk -o NAME,PARTFLAGS
```

However this doesn’t seem to work for all partition types. Add any other required fields after PARTFLAGS. You can list all available fields with lsblk -h

Edited 3 October to correct typo and add:

Looks like you can get better flag information that may help using parted:

```
sudo parted -l
```

It should be possible to process the output of this to get the flags you need.

Comment: Perhaps you meant PARTFLAGS  instead of PARTNUMBER (unknown) , but I've tried it and the diag flag that is reported by gparted does not show up.  Also with lsblk -O to see all fields; nothing looks like it could be hiding that flag. And the manual only gives that vague thing about diagnostics, but does not give it a numeric value or location.

Comment: Yes I did mean PARTFLAGS, I think the annoying spell checking on my iPad came into play. Sorry. I got the same result on my systems, hence the “should” comment, although the partitions with DIAG did return a hex value that could have been useful

Comment: I didn't see any likely hex values.  Partflags showed a zero.  I did find that in Windows 10 Disk Management, those partitions are described as Microsoft Recovery partitions.  In Ubuntu one is ext4(!) and the other shows no partition type at all, so I assume Windows has its own partition format and does not bother with a partition signature beyond the flag.  I'll do some more exploring.  What I really want to know is how to back the bloody things up and how to script it reliably.

Comment: Is the parted command I added of any use? Are you just trying to backup the flags? Not sure why you might want to do that. You could always pipe the output of the parted command to a text file to save it for future reference.

Comment: That command is fine for human consumption, but I'm trying to script this stuff -- I need info a bash script can use.

Comment: Actually, the command I'd be more likely to use is "parted /dev/sda print" because this host has 6 drives with lots of partitions: LVM Raid and such.

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer because the conversation has helped me focus.  I'm also going to gather together what I've learned and ways to use it.  Thanks...